# Node - POST local file to remote endpoint using AXIOS

Tags: node.js, axios

I'm having a bit of trouble taking a local file on the NodeJS server and uploading it to a web endpoint. I keep getting error:

> AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400
> at settle (D:\myproject\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:1855:12)
> at IncomingMessage.handleStreamEnd (D:\myproject\node_modules\axios\dist\node\axios.cjs:2712:11)
> at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
> at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {   code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing wrong. I've poured over a lot of posts and seem to be structuring my AXIOS post request correctly?

```
try {
    const fileStream = await fs.createReadStream('./pathtofile.ext');
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('myFile', fileStream, 'pathtofile.ext');
    axios.post('https://my.endpoint.com', formData, {
            headers: {
                ...formData.getHeaders(),
            }
        })
        .then(res => res.data)
        .catch( err => console.log(err))
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

I'm at a bit of a loss, as I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong with such a simple task? The headers also appear to be correct when I call "getHeaders()", it's showing "`'content-type': 'multipart/form-data;`"

I appreciate any and all assistance!

Comment: could you please post content of pathtofile.ext?

Comment: It is a .w3g file, it's from Warcraft 3 replays.

Comment: oh wowww could you please post a little sample of it?

Comment: There is nothing readable, it's compiled I think. Example:
Warcraft III recorded game D   ÿê    m ù   PX3W2'  â €>S ‡h>7      WÖF¡xìXMlEžÝÛÛ”ôÇmÓØmÙeÜR;Pì]ÛqRU ü-˜"Ú€

Comment: It should be readable I believe

Comment: The `createReadStream` is a non-promise function, so you wouldn't need to use await to invoke it. It is an event-based function. Although your code seems fine, have you tried to replace `headers` with `{headers:{"Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary="+form._boundary}}`?

Comment: Is the issue with just one file or any file ?

Comment: you are sending invalid data to the server. how did you configure your server

Comment: Are you trying to make post requests as you read data from the file ? Or are you trying to post the whole file at once ?

Comment: What is the actual response body? Usually 400 responses are quite detailed. Try `console.error(err.response?.data)`. Also, what version of Axios are you using? It's been extremely unstable lately

Comment: It's hard to tell why your input is causing the server-side code to response with `Bad Request` because we know nothing about that code.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen — Incorrect. This is the [Node.js version of form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-) which tells you to use `createReadStream` in the documentation.

Comment: The built-in `FormData` in Node.js does not accept a `createReadStream`, however.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure why you're trying to read the file with a ReadStream, since you need the whole file to post it to your endpoint.

The benefits of using a ReadStream is to perform operations as you read the file. So with every chunk of the file you do something.

In this case, i believe all you need to do is just read the file and then firing your POST request.

You can do this by using **readFileSync** instead of **createReadStream**.

Your code should maybe go on this direction:

```
try {
    const fileContents = await fs.readFileSync('./pathtofile.ext',{encoding: 'the-right-encoding'});
    let formData = new FormData();

    formData.append('myFile', fileContents, 'pathtofile.ext');
    axios.post('https://my.endpoint.com', formData, {
        headers: {
            ...formData.getHeaders(),
        }
    })
    .then(res => res.data)
    .catch( err => console.log(err));
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err)
}
```

That way, the *await* keyword would have more sense, since you'll be waiting for the readFileSync promise to resolve.

Be sure to choose the right encoding for reading the file.

Also, since you're using Axios, you can check for the status of the upload by providing a callback function to the post method.

```
const onUploadProgress = (event) => {
    const percentage = Math.round((100 * event.loaded) / event.total);
    console.log(percentage);
  };
```

Usage: https://www.bezkoder.com/axios-file-upload/

Comment: See the docs for [form-data](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-)

Answer (score -2):

Firstly, you should go to a site like [Reqbin](https://reqbin.com/) and simulate the request to ensure your web endpoint is not the issue. I took the trouble to test your code with my own endpoint and it works perfectly. Most of the time, such issues are due to Authorization, Rate-limiting or something of that sort. Perhaps I could help out if I knew the kind of endpoint. Good luck.